# How to restore my Debian 10 OS from dropped laptop's SSD?

Tags: debian, boot, hard-disk, data-recovery, hardware

Lenovo Ideapad 330s-14IKB Type 81F4 dropped from about 3 ft.

It's always had an issue where I need to charge it before starting it up, otherwise it doesn't find the LVM?

Using [SystemRescue](https://system-rescue.org) (arch-based) I used `ddrescue -d -f /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/sdb test.logfile` to clone the internal 2TB (or 1.86) to an external (enclosed, M.2, for internal) of the same size. I am able to unlock the LVM from within systemrescue and mount the encrypted drive. I'm about to try to copy the files to another external once I format it.

I don't know how to recover an OS or which files to back up really. I'm going to back up the home folder at least if not all. But I want to restore what I had before with settings and everything (I do not have an external backup).

Assuming the clone M.2 fits inside the laptop (https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/330s-14ikb_330s-14ikbx_330s-15ikb_330s-15ikbx_hmm_201903.pdf) (I didn't look yet), if I replace the existing SSD, I should be able to boot and use it again with the clone? The ddrescue stated there were 0 bad areas or sectors.

I found something for the error that shows up that says to update initramfs and update-grub, but I'm not sure of how to do that.

Startup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnfvm.jpg

When I first booted from systemrescue USB, and chose to start from trying to find the disk (I forget what the option was called), but it let me unlock LVM, but then didn't find the disk again? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxzgk.jpg

So is trying to replace the cloned with the clone feasible or not?

Answer (score 0):

> It's always had an issue where I need to charge it before starting it up, otherwise it doesn't find the LVM?

Not sure what this means, or which relevance has to your problem.

Most likely the fall has damaged some of your laptop's hardware (screen, etc.) but the SSD is fine. If you remove the SSD and mount it on a working laptop of the same type, it should work. Otherwise, put it in an USB enclosure and use it as an external USB SSD on another laptop.